# IIS can't read data (HTTP GET requests) from node.js app

Tags: node.js, get, iis-7.5

I hired a VPS (Windows Server 2008) with the aim of hosting a website. 
So i configured IIS 7.5 to run a html website.
The website reads data (HTTP GET requests) from a little node.js application running on the same VPS on port 3000.

On the other hand, for every GET call i am getting:

```
failed to load resource the server responded with a status of 404 (not found)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok my fault. I needed to change the http request from

```
$.get( "/myfunction", function( data ) {
});
```

to

```
$.get( "http://localhost:3000/myfunction", function( data ) {
});
```

Comment: the problem with this solution is that the HTTPS calls only work from inside the VPS, not from the outside.